# FluentValidation : Is it possible to add a RuleSet while invoking a validator using ValidateAndThrow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

For example, I have a Person Validator

```
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person> {

   public PersonValidator() {

      RuleSet("Names", () => {
      RuleFor(x => x.Surname).NotNull();
      RuleFor(x => x.Forename).NotNull();
 });

 RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotEqual(0);
 }
}
```

How can I specify the RuleSet when invoking the Validator using ValidateAndThrow

Usually this is what is done while calling ValidateAndThrow

```
public class ActionClass
{
  private readonly IValidator<Person> _validator;
  public ActionClass(IValidator<Person> validator)
  {
   _validator=validator
  }

  public void ValidateForExample(Person model)
  {
    _validator.ValidateAndThrow(model)

   //When there is no error I can continue with my operations
  }
}
```

I understand that Ruleset can be passed as parameter when caling **Validate**

I'd like to know if it can be done using **ValidateAndThrow** as well ?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation/DefaultValidatorExtensions.cs):

```
public static void ValidateAndThrow<T>(this IValidator<T> validator, T instance)
{
    var result = validator.Validate(instance);

    if(! result.IsValid)
    {
        throw new ValidationException(result.Errors);   
    }
}
```

It doesn't allow it by default, but there's nothing stopping you from creating your own little extension method that also takes in a ruleset name, like so:

```
public static class ValidationExtensions
{
    public static void ValidateAndThrow<T>(this IValidator<T> validator, T instance, string ruleSet)
    {
        var result = validator.Validate(instance, ruleSet: ruleSet);

        if (!result.IsValid)
        {
            throw new ValidationException(result.Errors);
        }
    }
}
```